# How to set a strict memory limit to node js application?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I want to strictly limit allowed memory to my Node Js application.

When I start an application with `max_old_space_size=512` and start to fill some array with a lot of objects in a loop - application starts to consume more than 512 MB. It becomes even 1 GB.

So if I understand correctly `max_old_space_size` doesn't guarantee that application will stop after it reaches the limit.

Is there any flag/parameter/configuration for Node Js to force an application to throw an exception when it reaches the defined memory limit?

Comment: consider using ulimit or cgroups?

Comment: Thank you for the good idea. I'm not sure that Node Js will know about it or not though. I want to let it know that it has a limit.